# Spring Boot on AWS not starting

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spring-boot

I'm trying to deploy a Spring Boot application as described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/deploying-a-spring-boot-application-on-aws-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk/). However, my Spring Boot app doesn't boot (which, according to the documentation, makes sense, because it needs to run on port 5000). However, when I try to change the port by adding an Env variable (SERVER_PORT=5000), I get the error:

```
Unable to validate settings: Environment named springBootEb1-env-1 is in an invalid state for this operation. Must be Ready.
```

So, it seems I'm going in circles. I tried cloning the environment, but now I have two failing environments. How can I fix this?

Comment: I presume you saw [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/720039/aws-environment-named-is-in-an-invalid-state-for-this-operation-must-be-re) already?

Comment: @MordechayS Yes, that's why I mentioned the cloning.

Comment: they also suggest a total rebuild. Did you try that?

Comment: Gr. I did that now, and, yes, 1 hour later, the env is rebuilt, and it seems to be working. However, in the meantime I set up Google Cloud, and I'm continuing with that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm summarizing the answer given in the back-and-fourth comments:*

The issue where `AWS` prompts a `Environment named [NAME] is in an invalid state` message, seems to be a bit problematic.

In [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/720039/aws-environment-named-is-in-an-invalid-state-for-this-operation-must-be-re) question on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/), two suggestions are made:

1. Clone the enviroment.
2. Rebuild the enviroment.

In the case of the OP, the second - a rebuild - solved the issue.